# Unable to fetch the list column of AWS DynamoDB in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin and AWS DynamoDB. I am new to both technologies. What I am doing now is I am trying to scan data from a table of DynamoDB. I know how to scan it. But the problem is that one of the column has List data type.

I have a table called item with the following columns.

[image]

Note in particular the Images field.

In Kotlin Android, I scan the table like this.

```
val dynamoDBClient = AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().credentialsProvider)
            val fetchedItems: ArrayList<Any> = ArrayList();

            val scanRequest = ScanRequest().withTableName(MainApplication.DB_TABLE_ITEMS);
            scanRequest.exclusiveStartKey = lastEvaluatedKey

            val scanResult = dynamoDBClient.scan(scanRequest)
            scanResult.items.forEach { item ->
                Log.i("ITEM_NAME", item.get("Name")?.s)
                val viewItem = ItemDO()
                viewItem.id = item.get("Id")?.s
                viewItem.description = item.get("Description")?.s
                viewItem.name = item.get("Name")?.s
                viewItem.userId = item.get("UserId")?.s
                viewItem.images = item.get("Images")?.ns
                fetchedItems.add(viewItem)
                Log.i("IMAGES_COUNT", item.get("Images")?.ns?.size.toString())
            }
```

But this

```
item.get("Images")?.ns
```

always return null even if the data exists in the column as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Why my code is not fetching the list data type but others?

Answer (score 2):

The code looks good and should be returning data for all the attributes irrespective of their type. I have equivalent piece of code in java that works as expected. Can you try inspecting the value returned by `item.get("Images")` before making the null-safe call. Type of the value returned by `item.get("Images")` is `AttributeValue` and so there is a possibility that the value gets lost in the course of implicit type conversion.